# Change string that contains a polygon points as latitude and longitude to acceptable format for leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet

I have a string as below:

"[[38.0331941572647,46.4061641693115], [38.0330673980052,46.4073014259338], [38.0342335749183,46.4073550701141], [38.0342166739362,46.4078593254089], [38.0355011374604,46.4079129695892], [38.0357461970214,46.4062607288361], [38.0331941572647,46.4061641693115]]"

which is sent from server side to javascript via ajax request with this code:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "_Index.aspx/GetPolygons",
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccessLoadPolygons,
            failure: function (response) {
                //alert(response.d);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                //alert(response.d);
            }
        });
```

on success request, I'm using leaflet library for draw polygon on map as below:

```
function OnSuccessLoadPolygons(response) {
        var polygons = response.d;
        $(polygons).each(function () {              
            L.polygon(latlngs, { color: 'aqua' }).addTo(mymap);
                      });
    }
```

but unfortunately leaflet acceptable format is like this:

[[38.0331941572647,46.4061641693115], [38.0330673980052,46.4073014259338], [38.0342335749183,46.4073550701141], [38.0342166739362,46.4078593254089], [38.0355011374604,46.4079129695892], [38.0357461970214,46.4062607288361], [38.0331941572647,46.4061641693115]]

without double quotes.
how can I parse my string to leaflet acceptable format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code as below:

L.polygon(JSON.parse(latlngs), { color: 'aqua' }).addTo(mymap); });

And problem is solved...